# Creating a relationship with a calculated field

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I am trying to create a relationship between 2 tables in Access. In one table I have customers, in another I have areas by postal region. In the customers table I have all the usual address information and a simple calculated field which is just the country code and the first 2 characters of a post code. For example United Kingdom, Birmingham 1 would be "UKB1" and United Kingdom Hull would be "UKHU". In the other table we have these 4 character codes (not calculated like the customer table) alongside a regional number and member of staff.

Access is stating that it cannot create the relationship due to it coming from a calculated field.

How do I get around this without having to manually enter the data into the customer table?

Comment: Play by the rules. Modify your tables to have fields that do allow to create a relation between the two tables.

Comment: @Gustav This means manual data entry (which is needless)

Comment: Calculated fields should not be stored in a table, instead they should be calculated on demand when needed (e.q. in a query).

Comment: I didn't even know you could store a calculation in a table.  Why not just use an Update query to update the fields in the table based on your calculation?  Presumably the data in a given record will never change, there's no need to calculate anything "on the fly".  Just have the Update query do the calculation and write the result into the fields, and then your tables can join properly.

Comment: _This means manual data entry_ .. No. Data can be inserted in many ways - in a form, from an append query, ...

Comment: Why not use autonumber PK and numeric FK to link tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use code to maintain the extra column. So, in the form(s) that allow edit of that customer, just put in the post code or whatever field a after update event for that control on that form that "shoves" into that country code column the first 2 characters.

For example, like this:

```
Private Sub PostalCode_AfterUpdate()

    Me!CountryCode = Left(Me.PostalCode, 2)


End Sub
```

Now, above will automatically take care of any edits, or new records you enter.

However, that does not address existing records. For that, you want to run an update query once to "fill out" this new column for existing data.

So, fire up query builder, add that table, and change query type to "update query".

So, you get/have something like this:

[image]

Of course, you could also I suppose hit Ctrl-G to get to command (immediate) window, and type in this:

```
currentdb.Execute "UPDATE tblHotels SET CountryCode = Left([postalCode],2)"
```

So, immediate window, or query builder. You simple add that new column, and fill it out.

As noted, with the simple after update event attached to the post-code in your edit form, then the value will be thus maintained without any extra efforts from that point forward.

And, now that you have a plain column, then  you are free to build queries etc. that will allow join of that 2nd PostalRegion table.

I suspect (doubt) that you need to enforce RI, but regardless, with a real living column of country code, then you are free to join in that "region" table for any query you build.